# Trouble with 'artifacts' appearing on curved surfaces wiiith shiny material

Tags: materials

could anyone help me with troubleshooting what these 'artefacts' are which are appearing please? It becomes more apparent when the roughness is turned down. I've tried rebuilding the mesh in meshmixer but get the same problem. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: hello, could you please share just the part you're showing? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: check the normals.